# The filename or extension is too long

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, compilation, compiler-errors

I try to compile project using PowerShell command.
Problem is that there is a lot of arguments (75000 characters)

When I try to run compilation I got error:

> This command cannot be run due to the error: The filename or extension is too long.

I have also changed value in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled but it didn’t helped.
I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Do you know where can be problem?

Comment: There was a similar thread recently: There is a max length in characters of commandline input in Windows. The limit is at around 32k or so. I think you should look for a different attempt. Maybe splatting helps

Comment: yeah, no way. 75k is overkill

Comment: There is no way to break that up or run it in several commands? Use file data as input or something else. I feel this is not a limitation you should be restricted by.

Comment: Can u post the sample of your so that it will be helpful to give you a solution

Comment: Did someone get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this grabs anyone else. I received this error but the real problem was my StartInfo.Arguments value was too big. It had nothing to do with the filename I was specifying.